# Could face_recognition.face_landmarks support cnn mode?

Tags: python, image

we can use face_recognition get face_landmarks_list,Could face_recognition.face_landmarks support cnn mode?

```
image = face_recognition.load_image_file("test.jpg")

face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It supports cnn

```
 import face_recognition
 image = face_recognition.load_image_file("my_picture.jpg")
 face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model="cnn")
```

See this example to try
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/find_faces_in_picture_cnn.py

Comment: Thank you, But I want to get face_landmarks_list by cnn model, something like [{'bottom_lip': [(260, 419), (244, 436),  ...

Comment: Yes, this return a rectangle, actually we need poses about eyes etc.